# Generating a random variable with specific mean and variance

Tags: python, variables, matplotlib, random

I am new to `Python` and I am wondering If I can simulate a process where a variable follow a normal distribution with specific mean and variance

I am working on the Vasicek model and I found the distribution of the stochastic rate as:

[image]

Is it possible to generate this with a graph via `matplotlib` ?

Comment: What's wrong with Python's [`random.gauss(mu, sigma)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.gauss)?

Answer (score 0):

The approach that generalises to *any* distribution is to

1) draw a uniform random number in the range [0, 1).

2) Apply the *quantile* function of your distribution to that random number.

The result of the quantile function will then have the distribution that you require. Other methods such as Box Muller work well for normal distributions, and can be faster, if a little more fiddly to set up.